# Easiest way to "Mock" out an object implementing a property-only protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, mocking, protocols

Excuse me for my crazy needs, but I'm creating a bunch of property-only protocols in a framework I'm writing.

```
@protocol SomePropertiesOfAnObjectThing <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *larry;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *curly;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *moe;

@end
```

Is there a way, more importantly an easy way, to "mock" out an object that implements this protocol?

```
id<SomePropertiesOfAnObjectThing> thingy = [ProtocolObject fromProtocol:@protocol(SomePropertiesOfAnObjectThing)];

thingy.larry = @"fizz";
thingy.curly = @"buzz";
thingy.moe = @"bar";
```

The 2 things I'm trying to avoid:

1. Explicitly creating a new class
2. 3rd party dependencies (such as OCMock)

I will shower anyone who can show me a clean and easy way with up votes (well, 1 at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My naïve solution is as follows:

```
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(foo:)];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    NSString *argument;
    [anInvocation getArgument:&argument atIndex:2];
    if (argument) {
        NSString *setterName = NSStringFromSelector(anInvocation.selector);
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(3, [setterName length]-4);
        NSString *propertyName = [[setterName substringWithRange:range] lowercaseString];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setFoo:value:) withObject:propertyName withObject:argument];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(foo:) withObject:argument];
    }
}

- (id)foo:(id)key
{
    return self.properties[key];
}

- (void)setFoo:(id)key value:(id)value
{
    self.properties[key] = value;
}

- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return self.properties[key];
}

- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    self.properties[key] = value;
}
```

I will update with a cleaner version later as I optimize for value types and the such.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about protocols is you're only making a promise to the compiler that a certain Class will implement the methods defined in the protocol. It is up to you to create a Class that actually provides implementations for the methods. Properties defined in a protocol are not auto-synthesized by a Class that declares to conform to a protocol, you need to define the underlying ivar and implement setters and getters for each property defined in the protocol to fully conform to it.

In other words, `thingy` up there doesn't get these properties for free just because it conforms to the protocol.

Comment: I contend OCMock accomplishes this. I'm looking for a solution that does not involve copying the entire framework.

Comment: That's fine, I'm telling you that protocols alone cannot accomplish this.